# JavaFX 8: TableColumn setPrefWidth doing nothing if user manually resizes the column

Tags: javafx, resize, tableview

I need to give my users the ability to resize the columns of a TableView in JavaFX 8.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

private TableView table = new TableView();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(300);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");

    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");

    final Button button = new Button("Resize!");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Pref Width before resizing: "+firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
            System.out.println("Width before resizing: "+firstNameCol.getWidth());
            firstNameCol.setPrefWidth(100);
            System.out.println("Pref Width after resizing: "+firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
            System.out.println("Width after resizing: "+firstNameCol.getWidth());
        }

    });
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label,button, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

If you click on the button, the first column resizes. If you manually resize the first column and then click on the button, the first column does not resize and getWidth and getPrefWidth return different values!

I understand it's a "preferred" width, but there is no "setWidth" method, only "getWidth".

If I set maxWidth and minWidth, the column isn't resizable anymore, so I can't use these methods.

Does anyone know what I could do to set the effective width of a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set both the min and max width, and immediately after set them to their "default" values back.

```
column.setPrefWidth(newWidth);
column.setMinWidth(newWidth);
column.setMaxWidth(newWidth);

column.setMinWidth(0);
column.setMaxWidth(5000);
```

This way, the column is forced to be resized by the first three instructions and keeps the correct width; the last two instructions ensure that the column is still resizable in any way.

Comment: Thank you. This solution fixed my problem of certain TableColumns were ignoring the setPrefWidth value.
By the way, this still appears to be an issue in JDK 17.